# How to print single string and not object?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with a simple **reactive form** and after entering **firstName**, **lastName** and **Answer** I'm able to print out the values in the console like this:

> {firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Smith", answer: {…}}

However, I want to print out the value of answer as a simple string and NOT an object.

**Expected Result:**

> {firstName:"Peter", lastName:"Smith", answer:'Yes'}

Does anyone have any idea how to make this happen?

Here's my code: [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wvrkv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: You could always `console.log` this instead: `Object.assign({}, this.searchform.value, { answer: this.searchform.value.answer.label })`

Comment: You can literally copy that code in your stackblitz as is to see it... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvpmjk

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel thanks a lot bro!

Comment: JSON.stringify(this.searchform.value); try this or you can directly use Json pipe in html like {{ searchform.value |  json }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `optionLabel="label"` property from your `p-dropdown`, and intialise the answers object with a `value`, and a `label`:

```
this.answers = [
  { label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' },
  { label: 'No', value: 'No' },
];
```

This will now print in your expected format.

**[Here is a fork of the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpmjf7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input bro!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const newObj = {
   'firstName': this.searchform.value.firstName,
   'lastName': this.searchform.value.lastName,
   'answer': this.searchform.value.answer.label,
};
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you have an array inside and you gotta access the value of the array

```
console.log(this.searchform.value.firstName);
console.log(this.searchform.value.lastName);
console.log(this.searchform.value.answer.label);
```

Comment: I don't want to print them one by one. I want to print them all out in a single object like I showed in my question